# Has there been any sea battles in W40k?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Does the W40k lore/history contain any battles fought at sea (or under it)?

I'm just wondering because I've never seen a sea-faring ship in W40k.

Comment: Armageddon 3rd war. there is talk about ork ships. Also there are some newer novels where they speak about Sea battles. cant remember the name of the book other than it is fairly recent. Lastly I remember reading about some sea battles in Double Eagle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Kraken](http://www.blacklibrary.com/all-products/kraken-ebook.html)

The only piece of lore I've read which involved any battles fought at sea was [Kraken](http://www.blacklibrary.com/all-products/kraken-ebook.html).

> The Space Wolves forge new sagas as they hunt a monstrous beast of the oceans and battle the alien menace of the tyranids.

The description for the story is actually incorrect, it's about a single Space Wolf. The lone Space Wolf hunting a massive 'nid at sea on some alien planet.

I think it cuts back and forth between the Space Wolf's time as a human sailor on Fenris and the battle he's having with the 'nid.